# Reload Document Ready after Ajax Response Injection to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that uses a color picker, this is defined in the `Document Ready` with the form select input tags. But I require to access some data trough AJAX in another page and have the response replace that form. When I do this, the jquery colorpicker stops working. I guess it would be cool to reload the `Document Ready` or something.

Otherwise I think my only option is JSON to pass the variables from PHP output to jquery and then back to html, right?

Comment: Do you have a live demo? There should be an easier way. I'm thinking show/hide the color picker when it's needed. jQuery is picky about event handlers on dynamic content but if it's in the page the whole time you should be good.

Answer (score 6):

There are two basic ways to accomplish this.  The first is to make the function which initializes your color picker callable from other code.  The other is to manually retrigger the document's ready event.  The former requires a small modification to your color picker code, but the latter will re-execute **all functions bound to document.ready!**  Be sure that's what you want before you do it.  :-)

```
// option one

function setupColorPicker() {
    // do color picking magic
}

$(document).ready(setupDatePicker);

$.ajax(options).done(setupColorPicker);

// option two

$(document).ready(function() {
    // do color picking magic
});

$.ajax(options).done(function() {
    $(document).trigger("ready"); // probably has unintended side-effects!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the color picker initializing script run from it's own function and call that once in document ready and again in the callback of your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You should register the events using the `live` or the `delegate` method:

- http://api.jquery.com/live/
- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 0):

Passing back the data from server as JSON will not only accomplish your goal but will also boost the performance(SPEED) of the application and also save you bytes of bandwidth. If you still want to inject response as plain html simply initialiZe the color picker plugin in a function and call the function after your ajax success callback.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //page is ready

    function colorpicker(){
      //initialize your color picker

    }

    $.ajax({
      url: 'serverpage.cshtml', //whatever server page
      data: {data1: data1},
      success: function(){
        //append the response into the designated form or div
        colorpicker(); //fire the color picker function to refresh
      } 
    });
});
```